# Why is custom CSS style not applied for another user?

Tags: css, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

Have been using the [blog post](https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-%e2%80%93-part-iii/) to customize Top Navigation of my Site Collection in SharePoint 2010 using SharePoint designer and my credential. I am getting the results as expected when I view the sites with my credentials.

But when another user logs into the sitecollection and navigates through the sites and pages, CSS style is not being applied. I modified the Master page to move the search box out of the Top Navigation bar, all these changes are reflected only the CSS styles are being applied.

Any help to resolve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have those user cleared their browser cache of old stylesheets?

Comment: To eliminate this issue, I logged into the site from my machine with another set of credentials, styles are not being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops I had to check in the CSS files uploaded in the Style Library using SharePoint Site. For some reason checking in SharePoint Designer is not working.